# kdb q - oracle access with babel fails

Tags: kdb

I have installed babel (interface between kdb and other dbs such as oracle) from [here](https://github.com/CharlesSkelton/babel/blob/master/dist/babel.zip). After copying the oracle8 driver to the `babel/lib` folder I run the command from the [babel documentation page](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Babel)

```
java -Xmx1024m -Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=10000 
      -cp "babel.jar:lib/ojdbc8.jar" de.skelton.babel.Babel 6868 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

which gives me

```
$ java -Xmx1024m -Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=10000 -cp "babel.jar:ojdbc8.jar" de.skelton.babel.Babel 6868 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Error: Could not find or load main class de.skelton.babel.Babel
```

I tried to run the alternative

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar babel.jar 6868 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

which gives

```
Babel for kdb+ v1.34 2014.03.24

Error: could not load jdbc driver. Exiting.
```

I am running this on Windows 7 and have the following jre installed

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b31)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b31, mixed mode)
```

Comment: There's an oracle driver for kdb at  https://github.com/effbiae/oraq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, perhaps you need to use a semi-colon as separator in the classpath arg? e.g.

```
java -Xmx1024m -Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=10000 -cp "babel.jar;lib/ojdbc8.jar" de.skelton.babel.Babel 6868 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```